# How can I prevent my external hard drive from automatically poweríng on right after I unmounted it?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, external-hdd, unmount

I've got a USB3 external hard drive connected to my laptop running 14.04. Every time I want to disconnect it, using "safely remove", the hard drive turns off, but then immediately turns on again.

I don't want to unplug it, while it's still running. So I'd really appreciate tips on how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, my system does the same thing but I've never had a problem with data being damaged. I have heard that USB 3.0 devices keep enough power to safely spin down and remove the read/write heads.

Comment: Related question: [USB 3.0 hard drives don't spin down when “safely removed” from Nautilus](http://askubuntu.com/questions/567005/usb-3-0-hard-drives-dont-spin-down-when-safely-removed-from-nautilus?rq=1)

Comment: More closely  related: [Ejecting a USB 3.0 drive connected to USB 3.0 port reconnects immediately](http://askubuntu.com/questions/550573/ejecting-a-usb-3-0-drive-connected-to-usb-3-0-port-reconnects-immediately?rq=1)

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of very similar questions: [External USB Hard Disk Drive Keep spinning even after safely remove!](http://askubuntu.com/q/716782/301745)

Comment: And there's a bug report! [Automatic remount of safely removed usb 3.0 drive](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/792085)

Comment: [The answer on "Ejecting a USB 3.0 drive connected to USB 3.0 port reconnects immediately"](http://askubuntu.com/a/667134/301745) worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

My USB 3 external drive does the same thing. If found references on the Internet that say it's a USB 3 problem. Plugging the drive into a USB 2 port and it'll act the way you expect it to. Try that, and report back.